# Move Object Every few Seconds

Tags: c++, sfml

My question is how can I move an object every few seconds while another objects can be moved independently when I press the keyboard.

So for example:

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case  sf::Event::Closed: 
            window.close(); 
            break;

        case sf::Event::KeyPressed: 
            m_mo[0]->move(0.f, 50.f); //move when keyboard is pressed
            break;
        }
    }
    m_mo[1]->move(0.f, 50.f); //move every 10 seconds

    window.clear();
    window.draw(m_mo[0]);
    window.draw(m-mo[1]);
    window.display();
    }
```

Anyone who got a time to give me an example please!

Comment: Check the difference between the current time and the last time the rectangle was moved. Using the [standard C++ chrono library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) it's very easy.

Comment: Nice one. I guess it's easier. For any chance could you give me an example? Like what is the statement that preceeds the rectanlge.move line if I want it to move every 10 seconds. I don't want to check the current and last time, I want to move it every 10 seconds. Meaning, while the (window.isOpen()) is running, so every 10 seconds the compiler tells to rectangle.move to move.

Comment: You simply need to keep a variable that records the last time it was moved. Each loop, get the current time and compare it with the time you recorded, if it's more than 10 seconds then move it and record the new "last moved" time. Repeat. You'll learn much more reading the chrono library docs to find how to to do this than if somebody just codes it for you.

Comment: Right. I would learn much more. Still, I am not sure how it works.

Comment: You commands will "teleport" your object by 50 pixels every 10 seconds. Don't you want ti to smoothly move a distance of 50 pixels over 10 seconds? So it's at 5 pixels after a second, at 10 after 2 seconds and so on?

Answer (score 0):

**SFML** does provide two classes for this purpose, [Time](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Time.php) and [Clock](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Clock.php). These can be used like the following.

```
sf::Clock clock;
sf::Time time;

time = clock.restart();
// wait some time
sf::Time ellapsed = clock.restart() - time;
sf::Int32 ellapsedMiliseconds = ellapsed.asMiliseconds();
```

**More information for time [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/system-time.php)**